# azure devops clone release with different stage security settings with inheritance set to off

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-security

I have a setup to deploy code via azure release pipeline with stages deploying to different env. I have created security settings with different for each stage in a release and I did this with Inheritance set to off on each stage.

For some reason when I clone a release pipeline with above setting all the security settings for stage are set to default in cloned pipeline. Is there a way I could completely replicate a release pipeline with with respective changes for a stage.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understanding the behaviour you are experimenting, the "clone" functionality does not copy over the parameters of the pipeline/stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I could completely replicate a release pipeline with with respective changes for a stage.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and is not a bug. There is no way to fix it at present.

As we know, the security settings is used for the build/release pipeline, security settings with different for each stage in a release should not be cloned, Otherwise, it may cause information security issue with security settings inheritance set to off. If you do not want to share the permissions of the pipeline after cloning to others.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.